# Eigen + MKL not working on Ubuntu. Works on OSX

Tags: ubuntu, eigen, intel-mkl

I have a physics simulation that relies on diagonalizing large hermitian matrices via Eigen.  I recently switched on MKL, which works very well on Mac OSX to accelerate the diagonalization.  But I can't get it to work on Ubuntu with the same code (i.e. I get no speed improvement and no multi-threading).

I have tried both sparse and dense matrix representations and both ComplexEigenSolver and SelfAdjointEigenSolver.

I using Eigen 3.3.3 and MKL 2018.u1 on Ubuntu and have followed the direction on this page: https://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/TopicUsingIntelMKL.html and other Eigen documentation.

The compilation and link lines are:

```
g++ -I/home/.../Development/physics/googletest/googletest/include -I/home/.../Development/googletest/googletest/include -I/home/.../lapack-3.7.1/LAPACKE/include -I/opt/intel/compilers_and_libraries/mac/mkl/include -I/usr/local/include/eigen3 -I/home/.../boost-inst/include -I/home/.../eigen3 -I/usr/local/include/boost -I/usr/local/include -O3 -Wall -Wno-sign-compare -std=gnu++11 -fopenmp -I/include -c -o obj/MajoranaKitaevHamiltonian.o src/MajoranaKitaevHamiltonian.cc

g++ obj/main.o obj/defs.o obj/kitaev.o obj/BasisState.o obj/DisorderParameter.o obj/KitaevHamiltonian.o obj/KitaevHamiltonianBlock.o obj/Spectrum.o obj/MajoranaDisorderParameter.o obj/NaiveMajoranaKitaevHamiltonian.o obj/MajoranaKitaevHamiltonian.o obj/Correlators.o obj/Timer.o obj/FockSpaceUtils.o obj/RandomMatrix.o obj/TSVFile.o -L/home/.../Development/physics/googletest/googletest/include -L/share/software/user/restricted/imkl/2018/mkl/lib/intel64 -L/share/software/user/restricted/imkl/2018.u1/lib/intel64/ -L/opt/intel/compilers_and_libraries/mac/mkl/lib -L/share/software/user/open/boost/1.64.0/lib -L/usr/local/lib -lboost_program_options -lboost_iostreams -lboost_system  -lboost_random -lmkl_core -lmkl_intel_thread -lmkl_core -lmkl_intel_ilp64 -liomp5 -fopenmp -o kitaev
```

(The redundant paths are to support both Mac and Ubuntu platforms)

Comment: Please add the exact compilation line you used.

Comment: So it works, but it is not faster than Eigen? Did you compile with `-DEIGEN_USE_MKL_ALL`?

Comment: I am using `#define EIGEN_USE_MKL_ALL`, which works on OSX.  The code runs fine, but I don't think it's calling into MKL because it is no faster.  I also tried connecting with `gdb` to get a backtrace and it looked just like the non-MKL backtrace.  Thank you!